# How to implement custom UserDetailsService or custom AuthenticationProvider in Spring authorization server 0.2.0

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

I am trying a new Spring Authorization server 0.2.0. I have managed to successfully run a sample application located at https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-authorization-server/tree/main/samples/boot/oauth2-integration.

Now, I am trying to add custom UserDetailsService to the authorization server. I have created a custom UserDetailsService with users saved in the Mysql database.

I have replaced this

```java
    @Bean
    UserDetailsService users() {
        UserDetails user = User.withDefaultPasswordEncoder()
                .username("user1")
                .password("password")
                .roles("USER")
                .build();
        return new InMemoryUserDetailsManager(user);
    }
```

with this

```java
    @Bean
    UserDetailsService users() {
        return new CustomUserDetailsService();
    }
```

Now Application throws an error "No AuthenticationProvider found for org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken" while trying to login in "Authorization Code" grant flow.

I don't know where to add my custom AuthenticationProvider. I have tried adding to DefaultSecurityConfig as below. But authorization code grant flow always returns invalid_client.

```java
    @Bean
    SecurityFilterChain defaultSecurityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider)
                .authorizeRequests(authorizeRequests ->
                        authorizeRequests.antMatchers("/actuator/**").permitAll()
                                .anyRequest().authenticated())
                .formLogin(withDefaults());
        return http.build();
    }
```

I think, I missed something about client authentication here as my custom authenticationProvider is having to authenticate the method only for users but not clients.

Now my question is how to add custom AuthenticationProvider or CustomUserDetailsService without adding AuthenticationProvider to the Spring authorization server.

**UPDATE:**

Here are my CustomUserDetailsService and CustomAuthenticationProvider

```java
    @Service
    public class CustomUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @Override
    public DcubeUserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        Supplier<UsernameNotFoundException> s =
                () -> new UsernameNotFoundException("Problem during authentication!");

        DcubeUser u = userRepository.findUserByUsername(username).orElseThrow(s);

        return new DcubeUserDetails(u);
       }
    }
```

```java
    @Service
    public class CustomAuthenticationProvider implements AuthenticationProvider {

    @Autowired
    private CustomUserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Override
    public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {
        String username = authentication.getName();
        String password = authentication.getCredentials().toString();

        CustomUserDetails user = userDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(username);
                return checkPassword(user, password);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean supports(Class<?> aClass) {
        return UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.class.isAssignableFrom(aClass);
    }

    private Authentication checkPassword(CustomUserDetails user, String rawPassword) {
        if (Objects.equals(rawPassword, user.getPassword())) {
            return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(user.getUsername(), user.getPassword(), user.getAuthorities());
        } else {
            throw new BadCredentialsException("Bad credentials");
        }
      }
    }
```

Here is my log

```
2021-10-27 09:08:34.387 TRACE 10928 --- [nio-8888-exec-7] o.s.s.w.s.HttpSessionRequestCache        : Did not match request /error to the saved one DefaultSavedRequest [http://localhost:8888/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=web-client&scope=web:write]
2021-10-27 09:08:34.387 TRACE 10928 --- [nio-8888-exec-7] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter (10/14)
2021-10-27 09:08:34.387 TRACE 10928 --- [nio-8888-exec-7] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking AnonymousAuthenticationFilter (11/14)
2021-10-27 09:08:34.387 TRACE 10928 --- [nio-8888-exec-7] o.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter  : Did not set SecurityContextHolder since already authenticated UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken [Principal=Ramesh, Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=WebAuthenticationDetails [RemoteIpAddress=0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, SessionId=D4FF0763B895353AC334140528DE35CD], Granted Authorities=[ADMIN]]
2021-10-27 09:08:34.387 TRACE 10928 --- [nio-8888-exec-7] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking SessionManagementFilter (12/14)
2021-10-27 09:08:34.387 TRACE 10928 --- [nio-8888-exec-7] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking ExceptionTranslationFilter (13/14)
2021-10-27 09:08:34.387 TRACE 10928 --- [nio-8888-exec-7] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking FilterSecurityInterceptor (14/14)
2021-10-27 09:08:34.387 DEBUG 10928 --- [nio-8888-exec-7] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Secured GET /error
2021-10-27 09:08:34.464 DEBUG 10928 --- [nio-8888-exec-7] s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter : Cleared SecurityContextHolder to complete request
2021-10-27 09:08:56.440 TRACE 10928 --- [nio-8888-exec-8] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Trying to match request against DefaultSecurityFilterChain [RequestMatcher=org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configurers.oauth2.server.authorization.OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfigurer$$Lambda$1085/0x0000000801355c90@32e7df65, Filters=[org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter@421d7900, org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter@42a7e7e1, org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter@55e88bc, org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter@20a116a0, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter@67e21ea2, org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.authorization.web.OAuth2AuthorizationEndpointFilter@e2ee348, org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.authorization.oidc.web.OidcProviderConfigurationEndpointFilter@5d67bf4d, org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.authorization.web.NimbusJwkSetEndpointFilter@1477d4e6, org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.authorization.web.OAuth2AuthorizationServerMetadataEndpointFilter@5ec3689b, org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.authorization.web.OAuth2ClientAuthenticationFilter@448fa659, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter@7c0a6f62, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.ui.DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter@4946dfde, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.ui.DefaultLogoutPageGeneratingFilter@45964b9e, org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter@554e9509, org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter@34ea86ff, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter@166a5659, org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter@4c12f54a, org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter@417b3642, org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor@22ed2886, org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.authorization.web.OAuth2TokenEndpointFilter@76219fe, org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.authorization.web.OAuth2TokenIntrospectionEndpointFilter@4c599679, org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.authorization.web.OAuth2TokenRevocationEndpointFilter@1bcf2c64]] (1/2)
2021-10-27 09:08:56.440 DEBUG 10928 --- [nio-8888-exec-8] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Securing POST /oauth2/authorize
2021-10-27 09:08:56.440 TRACE 10928 --- [nio-8888-exec-8] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter (1/22)
2021-10-27 09:08:56.441 TRACE 10928 --- [nio-8888-exec-8] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking SecurityContextPersistenceFilter (2/22)
2021-10-27 09:08:56.441 TRACE 10928 --- [nio-8888-exec-8] w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : Retrieved SecurityContextImpl [Authentication=UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken [Principal=Ramesh, Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=WebAuthenticationDetails [RemoteIpAddress=0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, SessionId=D4FF0763B895353AC334140528DE35CD], Granted Authorities=[ADMIN]]] from SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT
2021-10-27 09:08:56.441 DEBUG 10928 --- [nio-8888-exec-8] s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter : Set SecurityContextHolder to SecurityContextImpl [Authentication=UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken [Principal=Ramesh, Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=WebAuthenticationDetails [RemoteIpAddress=0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, SessionId=D4FF0763B895353AC334140528DE35CD], Granted Authorities=[ADMIN]]]
2021-10-27 09:08:56.441 TRACE 10928 --- [nio-8888-exec-8] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking HeaderWriterFilter (3/22)
2021-10-27 09:08:56.442 TRACE 10928 --- [nio-8888-exec-8] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking CsrfFilter (4/22)
2021-10-27 09:08:56.442 TRACE 10928 --- [nio-8888-exec-8] o.s.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter         : Did not protect against CSRF since request did not match And [CsrfNotRequired [TRACE, HEAD, GET, OPTIONS], Not [Or [org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configurers.oauth2.server.authorization.OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfigurer$$Lambda$1085/0x0000000801355c90@32e7df65]]]
2021-10-27 09:08:56.442 TRACE 10928 --- [nio-8888-exec-8] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking LogoutFilter (5/22)
2021-10-27 09:08:56.443 TRACE 10928 --- [nio-8888-exec-8] o.s.s.w.a.logout.LogoutFilter            : Did not match request to Ant [pattern='/logout', POST]
2021-10-27 09:08:56.443 TRACE 10928 --- [nio-8888-exec-8] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking OAuth2AuthorizationEndpointFilter (6/22)
2021-10-27 09:08:56.444 TRACE 10928 --- [nio-8888-exec-8] o.s.s.authentication.ProviderManager     : Authenticating request with OAuth2AuthorizationCodeRequestAuthenticationProvider (1/8)
2021-10-27 09:08:56.447 DEBUG 10928 --- [nio-8888-exec-8] o.s.s.web.DefaultRedirectStrategy        : Redirecting to http://localhost:8080/authorized?code=iaFZSqcRLeJucw2mx_HNgji1PWN9QPHaUZt0htdH2zc3_4hEPFoBamnijwuRcK2xTzOT_W4jCTne3AmjAKB2gyoVzod5otPfgB8WSLc_8-x2B13oapwhlWX4dBUUER2e
2021-10-27 09:08:56.447 TRACE 10928 --- [nio-8888-exec-8] o.s.s.w.header.writers.HstsHeaderWriter  : Not injecting HSTS header since it did not match request to [Is Secure]
2021-10-27 09:08:56.447 DEBUG 10928 --- [nio-8888-exec-8] s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter : Cleared SecurityContextHolder to complete request
2021-10-27 09:09:23.121 TRACE 10928 --- [io-8888-exec-10] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Trying to match request against DefaultSecurityFilterChain [RequestMatcher=org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configurers.oauth2.server.authorization.OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfigurer$$Lambda$1085/0x0000000801355c90@32e7df65, Filters=[org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter@421d7900, org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter@42a7e7e1, org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter@55e88bc, org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter@20a116a0, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter@67e21ea2, org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.authorization.web.OAuth2AuthorizationEndpointFilter@e2ee348, org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.authorization.oidc.web.OidcProviderConfigurationEndpointFilter@5d67bf4d, org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.authorization.web.NimbusJwkSetEndpointFilter@1477d4e6, org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.authorization.web.OAuth2AuthorizationServerMetadataEndpointFilter@5ec3689b, org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.authorization.web.OAuth2ClientAuthenticationFilter@448fa659, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter@7c0a6f62, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.ui.DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter@4946dfde, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.ui.DefaultLogoutPageGeneratingFilter@45964b9e, org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter@554e9509, org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter@34ea86ff, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter@166a5659, org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter@4c12f54a, org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter@417b3642, org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor@22ed2886, org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.authorization.web.OAuth2TokenEndpointFilter@76219fe, org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.authorization.web.OAuth2TokenIntrospectionEndpointFilter@4c599679, org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.authorization.web.OAuth2TokenRevocationEndpointFilter@1bcf2c64]] (1/2)
2021-10-27 09:09:23.122 DEBUG 10928 --- [io-8888-exec-10] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Securing POST /oauth2/token?grant_type=authorization_code&code=iaFZSqcRLeJucw2mx_HNgji1PWN9QPHaUZt0htdH2zc3_4hEPFoBamnijwuRcK2xTzOT_W4jCTne3AmjAKB2gyoVzod5otPfgB8WSLc_8-x2B13oapwhlWX4dBUUER2e&scope=dcube:write&redirect_uri=http://localhost:8888/authorized
2021-10-27 09:09:23.122 TRACE 10928 --- [io-8888-exec-10] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter (1/22)
2021-10-27 09:09:23.122 TRACE 10928 --- [io-8888-exec-10] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking SecurityContextPersistenceFilter (2/22)
2021-10-27 09:09:23.122 TRACE 10928 --- [io-8888-exec-10] w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : No HttpSession currently exists
2021-10-27 09:09:23.122 TRACE 10928 --- [io-8888-exec-10] w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : Created SecurityContextImpl [Null authentication]
2021-10-27 09:09:23.122 DEBUG 10928 --- [io-8888-exec-10] s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter : Set SecurityContextHolder to empty SecurityContext
2021-10-27 09:09:23.122 TRACE 10928 --- [io-8888-exec-10] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking HeaderWriterFilter (3/22)
2021-10-27 09:09:23.122 TRACE 10928 --- [io-8888-exec-10] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking CsrfFilter (4/22)
2021-10-27 09:09:23.122 TRACE 10928 --- [io-8888-exec-10] o.s.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter         : Did not protect against CSRF since request did not match And [CsrfNotRequired [TRACE, HEAD, GET, OPTIONS], Not [Or [org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configurers.oauth2.server.authorization.OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfigurer$$Lambda$1085/0x0000000801355c90@32e7df65]]]
2021-10-27 09:09:23.122 TRACE 10928 --- [io-8888-exec-10] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking LogoutFilter (5/22)
2021-10-27 09:09:23.122 TRACE 10928 --- [io-8888-exec-10] o.s.s.w.a.logout.LogoutFilter            : Did not match request to Ant [pattern='/logout', POST]
2021-10-27 09:09:23.122 TRACE 10928 --- [io-8888-exec-10] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking OAuth2AuthorizationEndpointFilter (6/22)
2021-10-27 09:09:23.123 TRACE 10928 --- [io-8888-exec-10] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking OidcProviderConfigurationEndpointFilter (7/22)
2021-10-27 09:09:23.123 TRACE 10928 --- [io-8888-exec-10] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking NimbusJwkSetEndpointFilter (8/22)
2021-10-27 09:09:23.123 TRACE 10928 --- [io-8888-exec-10] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking OAuth2AuthorizationServerMetadataEndpointFilter (9/22)
2021-10-27 09:09:23.123 TRACE 10928 --- [io-8888-exec-10] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking OAuth2ClientAuthenticationFilter (10/22)
2021-10-27 09:09:23.124 TRACE 10928 --- [io-8888-exec-10] o.s.s.authentication.ProviderManager     : Authenticating request with OAuth2ClientAuthenticationProvider (1/8)
2021-10-27 09:09:23.124  WARN 10928 --- [io-8888-exec-10] o.s.s.c.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder     : Encoded password does not look like BCrypt
2021-10-27 09:09:23.127 TRACE 10928 --- [io-8888-exec-10] o.s.s.w.header.writers.HstsHeaderWriter  : Not injecting HSTS header since it did not match request to [Is Secure]
2021-10-27 09:09:23.127 DEBUG 10928 --- [io-8888-exec-10] w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : Did not store empty SecurityContext
2021-10-27 09:09:23.127 DEBUG 10928 --- [io-8888-exec-10] w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : Did not store empty SecurityContext
2021-10-27 09:09:23.127 DEBUG 10928 --- [io-8888-exec-10] s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter : Cleared SecurityContextHolder to complete request
```

Comment: Let's see what we can figure out. First, can you provide a bit more info? I am not seeing where your custom authentication provider is coming from. Can you show your custom provider and custom `UserDetailsService`? And can you enable trace logs, ex.`logging.level.org.springframework.security=trace`, and provide the logs to show where you're getting stuck?

Comment: Sorry for the delayed reply. I have updated my question with custom `UserDetailsService` and `AuthenticationProvider` and logs also provided.

Comment: A couple of things I noticed. First, your `CustomUserDetailsService` has an `@Service`, and is additionally returned from an `@Bean` method. You should choose one approach. It may be that because your `@Bean` is in your config, that's where you're getting an error, but I'm not 100% sure. Second, you really should have your passwords hashed in the database. If the only reason to wire up a custom provider is to compare passwords in plain text, then you're much better off learning to hash the passwords, and not wiring a custom one.

Comment: Third, your logs indicate that client authentication is failing, with the line `Encoded password does not look like BCrypt`. So you are having an issue with password encoding there. I'm not sure if your authentication provider is overriding the client authentication providers that Spring Authorization Server is wiring up. May be best to remove your custom provider and get things working without it first. You may find you don't actually need it.

Comment: I have delete the @Beans and because of this `Encoded password does not look like BCrypt` i have used plain text passwords. Application has started successfully. But, as earlier Authorization code is not generating in response.

Comment: And also, the application works perfectly fine with out custom implementation of `UserDetailsService` or `AuthenticationProvider`.

Comment: Any way I managed to solve the issue. Please see the answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to delete following `Bean` from `DefaultSecurityConfig` class.

```
@Bean
UserDetailsService users() {
UserDetails user = User.withDefaultPasswordEncoder()
        .username("user1")
        .password("password")
        .roles("USER")
        .build();
   return new InMemoryUserDetailsManager(user);
 }
```

Add following method and an `Autowired` custom `AuthenticationProvider` to the same class

```
   @Autowired
   public void myCoolMethodName(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider);
   }
```

Now everything working as I expected.

The complete `DefaultSecurityConfig` will be like

```
@EnableWebSecurity
public class DefaultSecurityConfig {

@Autowired
private CustomAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider;

 @Bean
 PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
   return PasswordEncoderFactories.createDelegatingPasswordEncoder();
  }

@Bean
SecurityFilterChain defaultSecurityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
            .authorizeRequests(authorizeRequests ->
                    authorizeRequests.anyRequest().authenticated())
            .formLogin(withDefaults());
    return http.build();
  }

@Autowired
public void whateverMethodName(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider);
   }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

First, cross-check that you've made relatable changes in the security config file.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@ComponentScan("com.frugalis")
public class CustAuthProviderConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
  
    @Autowired
    private CustomAuthenticationProvider authProvider;
 
    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.authenticationProvider(authProvider);
    }
 
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and().httpBasic();
    }
}
```

The above code registers a custom authentication provider and authorizes users.

To create a **custom user service**, you need to implement the `UserDetailsService` interface and override the `loadUserByUsername()` method.

Create `UserDetailsServiceImp` class under `service` package.

```
public class UserDetailsServiceImp implements UserDetailsService {
  @Override
  public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {

    /*Here we are using dummy data, you need to load user data from
     database or other third party application*/
    User user = findUserbyUername(username);

    UserBuilder builder = null;
    if (user != null) {
      builder = org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User.withUsername(username);
      builder.password(new BCryptPasswordEncoder().encode(user.getPassword()));
      builder.roles(user.getRoles());
    } else {
      throw new UsernameNotFoundException("User not found.");
    }

    return builder.build();
  }

  private User findUserbyUername(String username) {
    if(username.equalsIgnoreCase("admin")) {
      return new User(username, "admin123", "ADMIN");
    }
    return null;
  }
}
```

Make sure to use the appropriate spring boot version and maven repositories.

For more, refer to this example:[Spring Security 5 - Custom UserDetailsService example](https://www.boraji.com/spring-security-5-custom-userdetailsservice-example)

Now define a **Custom Authentication Provider**.

```
@Component
public class CustomAuthenticationProvider implements AuthenticationProvider {

    boolean shouldAuthenticateAgainstThirdPartySystem = true;

    @Override
    public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {
        String name = authentication.getName();
        String password = authentication.getCredentials().toString();

        if (name.equals("admin") && password.equals("password")) {
            final List<GrantedAuthority> grantedAuths = new ArrayList<>();
            grantedAuths.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_USER"));
            final UserDetails principal = new User(name, password, grantedAuths);
            final Authentication auth = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(principal, password, grantedAuths);
            return auth;
        } else {
            return null;
        }

    }

    @Override
    public boolean supports(Class<?> authentication) {

        return authentication.equals(UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.class);
    }

}
```

In the above code, we have retrieved the Username and password from the Authentication object. Once We retrieve the Authentication Object and Credentials, we are validating the username and password.

You can perform database-based authentication, we have done a hard-coded validation here.

Once the user is valid we try and set `GRANTED_AUTHORITY` in the list of String and return an UserDetails Object to the Caller an Authentication object. Instead of spring-provided UserDetails, we can customize the User object set in principal and return.

[Custom Authentication Provider Spring Security](https://frugalisminds.com/using-custom-authentication-provider-spring-security/)

Comment: Hi, pranay thank you for you time. I don't think I can use class extends `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` as Authorization server already had `AuthorizationServerConfig` which creates a bean of `SecurityFilterChain`. Even then I tried everything you have written here, but the application throws exception **java.lang.IllegalStateException: Found `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` as well as `SecurityFilterChain`. Please select just one.**

Comment: I need to know how to configure `CustomAuthenticationProvider` in default `AuthorizationServerConfig` provided by spring authorization server (refer github link provided in question) with out effecting the default functionality of `OAuth2Authentication` provided for clients by spring authorization server

Comment: I'm also working on that , will update you ASAP

Comment: See my answer if you are still trying the same.  If you have any idea how to add custom claims to the access_token, Please share.

Comment: I don't understand. If we create our own UserDetailsService bean ,  why does the error indicate No Authentication Provider.  Isn't the default one (DaoAuthenticationProvider) still being created? The default provide should automatically pick up the userDetailsService custom bean we create.