# Enable Custom Login Workflow using Spring-Authorization-Server

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, authorization

I use spring-authoriation-server 0.2

I need to implement a login workflow which is based on a user-interaction on his mobile phone.

Which means instead of username/password custom page, I need to generate some information, and show as QR code. Then a user scans it, and can login.

Now, I have some problems to find the right place in the authorization server where I can integrate own workflow into the login page. I need to wait for the user, and then create the authorization code for the client. So any hints?

Comment: You could add it in your custom login page. Just write a custom login page with a controller. There is no difference to a username and password login, there you have to wait, too.

Comment: sure, this make sense. So there I just wait until some state in backend is in the right position. Then I would just submit nothing, and need to overwrite the authenticationprovider, where I just check for the stuff in backend instead of username and password. Where I can overwrite it, I think I saw somethink like this in another post here --> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69728514/how-to-implement-custom-userdetailsservice-or-custom-authenticationprovider-in-s

@dur can you answer this, so I can mark this as right answer?